# A question on a common surjetive map for proving uncountability of sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

With the aim of proving that something is uncountable, it's common to utilize the Cantor diagonal method to achieve one's goal. It's not hard to see that all of those arguments lie in proving the function given by
$$
f (\{\eta_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \dfrac{\eta_k}{2^{k}},
$$ for all sequences $\{\eta_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is sujective on $[0,1]$. Is there a good way of proving that given an $x\in[0,1]$ is possible to find a sequence $\{\eta_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f(\{\eta_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}})=x$, with each $n_k$ being 0 or 1?

Comment: It’s a fairly immediate consequence of the fact that the [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) are dense in the reals.

Comment: Surjection of the map $f$ looks stronger than being dense on $[0,1]$

Comment: It isn’t, though it takes a little work to show this; use the fact that each real number is the limit of an increasing sequence of dyadic rationals.

Comment: For me, it was true that each number has a binary representation, which is the motivation of the function.

Comment: It’s the fact that the dyadic rationals are dense that ensures that each real number has a binary representation.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how it implies it.

Comment: My edit was for a typo. Changed the subscript $i=1$ on the $\sum$ to $k=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\eta_1=0$ if $x<1/2,$ or $\eta_1=1$ if $x\ge 1/2.$ Let $x_1=\eta_1/2.$ Then $x_1\le x\le x_1+1/2.$

For $k\in\Bbb N,$ suppose that $x_k=\sum_{n=1}^k\eta_n/2^n$ and that  $x_k\le x\le x_k+1/2^k.$  Let $\eta_{k+1}=0$ if $x-x_k<1/2^{k+1},$ or $\eta_{k+1}=1$ if $x-x_k\ge 1/2^{k+1}.$ Let $x_{k+1}=x_k+\eta_{k+1}/2^{k+1}.$ Then we have $x_{k+1}\le x\le x_{k+1}+1/2^{k+1}.$

So by induction on $k\in\Bbb N$ we have $x_k\le x\le x_k+1/2^k$ for all $k\in \Bbb N.$ Therefore $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\eta_k/2^k=\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=x.$$ The construction (definition) of the sequence $(\eta_k)_{k\in \Bbb N}$  is sometimes called inductive but is more properly called a recursive construction.

If you want pedantic precision, append a sub-subscript "$x$" to each $\eta_k$.